# sending a string to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hi on my master page I have an area to do a search but my search code is on another page(content page) called Search.aspx

when I click the button to do a search query of my database I need to send the string from my master page to my search page and redirect.

**Search.aspx code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void PopulateWallPosts(string search)
    {
       //my search query code
    }
```

**Master Page:**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string search = TextBox2.Text;

    PopulateWallPosts(search);
    // this method works fine on local page
    // how do I send this to Search.aspx so when button is clicked im redirected to search.aspx and the content of search populates my wallposts?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = Request.QueryString["search"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
       PopulateWallPosts(search);
    }
}

private void PopulateWallPosts(string search)
{
   //my search query code
}
```

Master Page:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = TextBox2.Text;

    Response.Redirect("Search.aspx?search=" + Server.UrlEncode(search));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) property of the button/link:

```
<asp:Button PostBackUrl="Search.aspx" ID="search" runat="server" Text="Search" />
```

And in the `Search.aspx` page fetch the value from the Request. For example if the textbox is in the master page and is called `txtSearch`:

```
public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txtSearch = (TextBox)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("txtSearch");
        if (txtSearch != null)
        {
            var value = txtSearch.Text;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Garrith Graham, where is the textbox? In the master page? If yes does the Search.aspx derive from the same master?

Comment: @Garrith Graham, then you should be able to `var txtSearch = (TextBox)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("TextBox1");` to fetch the corresponding textbox in `Search.aspx` and use the `.Text` property to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

Just have your search box redirect to the search page, passing the arguments on the querystring.